# stm32f429 buildroot remote-debugging

Tags: remote-debugging, stm32, buildroot

there

I just learned how to use buildroot and followed one of the tutorials to flash the built images of linux kernel, U-Boot, etc. to a beagle bone. It's all good and fine. So I applied buildroot on the stm32f429-disc1 and flashed the images to the board. There is a bug on the busybox and I want to debug it. The question is how would I modify the openocd script below so that I can debug the booting process, presumably with gdb (server) open in another terminal ?

---

```
flash:
    cd $(dir_buildroot)/output/build/host-openocd-0.10.0/tcl && ../../../host/usr/bin/openocd \
    -f board/stm32f429discovery.cfg \
    -c "init" \
    -c "reset init" \
    -c "flash probe 0" \
    -c "flash info 0" \
    -c "flash write_image erase ../../../images/stm32f429i-disco.bin 0x08000000" \
    -c "flash write_image erase ../../../images/stm32f429-disco.dtb 0x08004000" \
    -c "flash write_image erase ../../../images/xipImage 0x08008000" \
    -c "reset run" -c shutdown
```

---

I've always been using Atollic Truestudio under windows to debug stm32 boards, and Atollic makes it super easy to debug the bootloader, etc. I googled a lot of tutorials, but it seems to me that most of them are to setup  for debugging applications in the user space. I am using Linux as the host machine, and I believe all I need are st-link/v2-1, openocd and gdb ?

Any comment is appreciated.

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug userspace applications, you will not use OpenOCD, but rather pure software debugging, using gdb and gdbserver. You can read https://bootlin.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-slides.pdf starting from slide 275 for more details.

Comment: Does this applies for `/sbin/init` as well?

Comment: Hi, Thomas thank you for the reply. I watched a lot of your presentations and they are very helpful. The question I have here is mainly to set a break point at, say, the entry point of u-boot or the Linux Kernel. Then I'd like to step through the codes. In this way, I can better understand of the booting process, as well as the Linux Kernel running on the embedded systems. Is this possible using OpenOCD + buildroot ? and maybe with the help of eclipse ? thank you.

Comment: Your initial question was about Busybox, which is a user-space application. Now you're talking about debugging the Linux kernel or U-Boot, so it's a totally different thing. For U-Boot debugging, you need a JTAG indeed. For the Linux kernel, you can use either a JTAG or kgdb.

Comment: Yes, I thought the bug was in the busybox, but I am not sure. Yes, the STM32F429-Disc1 board comes with a JTAG that is used as the debugger. Is there an online tutorial that I can watch to set up the buildroot + OpenOCD so that I can debug the U-Boot ? I think that is a good first step. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, Thomas - Can you show me a tutorial on how to debug the U-Boot created by the buildroot ? I am using the beaglebone as the platform now. Thank you.